# SAM CLI: organizing multiple Lambda functions that together form one REST API

Tags: aws-sam-cli

I would like to use Sam CLI to manage a group of Lambda functions that together form one REST API. Reading sources like [this one](https://manuchandrasekhar.medium.com/sam-template-configure-an-api-gateway-with-multiple-lambdas-921b38873389) it looks like the code for each Lambda function needs to be in a separate subdirectory. I'd rather not. I'd rather put them all in the main directory. I like my world better when I can see all my code files in one place side-by-side. Is this possible?